# Marshal data too short to load : Loading an array

Tags: ruby, windows, marshalling

```
DATA = [
[false, "aef012.documents", "path", 9, 1], [false, "test.documents", "path", 7, 1], 
[false, "test.documents", "path", 182, 2], [false, "test.sw", "path", 1, 3], 
[false, "test.rm_git_h1_hw", "path", 1, 4], [false, "test.rm_git_h1_mech", "path", 1, 5], 
[false, "test.rm_git_h1_others", "path", 1, 6], [false, "test.rm_git_h_doc", "path", 1, 7]
  ]

test_data = Marshal.dump(DATA)
#Returns some marshal data

File.open('test.txt', 'w') {|f| f.write(test_data) }
#360

DATA = Marshal.load File.read('test.txt')
# ArgumentError : marshal data too short.
```

What is wrong with the DATA array? Why am I getting the argument error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `DATA` is fine. This should be a windows-specific file IO issue. Code runs perfectly on my linux box. Try to check whether your file is written properly.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. When asking questions, it isn't necessary to preface, or artificially use the tags of the question in the title. Stack Overflow prefers natural question titles, just as you'd normally speak. The tags are used to sort things out and give hints to the search engines behind the scenes for us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is better to use binary mode (note the `b`) on Windows:

```
File.open('test.txt', 'wb') { |f| f.write(test_data) }

DATA = Marshal.load File.open('test.txt', 'rb').read
```

see: "[IO Open Mode](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/IO.html#method-c-new-label-IO+Open+Mode)"

Comment: Nuts! I was pulling got my hair trying to figure this out and this was the answer, thanks...